# Eclipse/PyDev/Django Import Requires Project Name

Tags: django, eclipse, import, pydev

Developing a project in Django with my IDE setup as Eclipse with PyDev.  The following import statement:

```
from polls.models import Poll, Choice
```

works when running the project from the command line via:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

However, built in error-checking with Eclipse fails to find polls.models ("unresolved import Port").  I can fix this by adding the project name before the class and then running this. That is, make the import statement:

```
from projectName.polls.models import Poll, Choice
```

The issue is that I'm collaborating on the project and can't do this.

**Question is: Is there a way to have Eclipse auto-detect or assume the projectName from the import statement?**

Comment: Naming the project is the right thing to do(tm). Implicit relative imports are made of pure evil.

Comment: Thanks, team members agree.  All new to Django, so we're still defining conventions.

Comment: You can also poke PYTHONPATH in Project Settings to fix this.

Comment: Using projectName is not a good idea. Never ever do this. It will fire back sometimes for sure. And it is definitely not the "right thing to do". Always create new app and place it somewhere on the PYTHONPATH. And than do 'from appName import'. But that is what you are already doing. I will answer below.

Comment: I'd put project name only in single file (like WSGI), one directory up the project. Then use explicit relative imports throughout the project (`from __future__ import absolute_import` + `from .polls.models import Poll, Choice`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using projectName on import statements is not a good idea.

When working with django/python start to use virtualenv. Especially when working with eclipse/pydev. You can than configure a new interpreter for every virtualenv. Just add the virtualenv to the list of interpreters under "Preferences > PyDev > Interpreter - Python" and be sure to add your djangoproject root to the PYTHONPATH on the same preferences page.

This is essentially what django does for you when running from the command line.